# honda civic 2000 model

Tags: honda, starting, civic, starter

I have a 2000 Honda Civic .... In hot weather, right after work, my car won't start. It just makes a click noise by the relay (solenoid?)...  I replaced the battery and it worked fine....  Then, a few weeks later, I got the same problem when as soon as I drive and motor is hot and I switch it off and want to start it again, then it just make a click sound by the relay. If I bridge the selonoid then it starts perfect...  I replaced the ignition and the selonoid but still have the same problem. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Did you 'bridge' to the small connector on the solenoid?

Comment: Yes I did nd then it starts up perfectly or kick start and then it starts

Answer (score 3):

If making a bridge across the solenoid always works, then you either need a new starter relay or you have a bad connection in one of the following places -

Small connector on the starter solenoid

Connections to the fuse in the starter circuit

Connections to the starter relay (on the switched side, not the coil)

It is also possible there is a bad connection to the battery

Comment: I checked everything even cleaned the earth cables

Comment: Have you tried a different relay?

Comment: And in hot weather after work then it won't start,  just hear a tick when I turn the key nd then I bridge the selonoid nd then it start

Comment: I realised after I use the aircon or the radio then it also doesn't want to start I'm clued upnow iI really Dnu anymore

Comment: Can you identify where the clicking sound is coming from when you try to start it?